# Trouble changing appearance of cells in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using the delegate method tableview: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath to make visual changes to my UITableViewCell's with. The problem is that this only seems to work after I scroll through the table. The cells that are shown before I scroll don't have a change until I scroll. My delegate method is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300.0f,100.0f);
}
```

Any ideas as to how I get the initial cells to look the same as they do once I scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the frame of a cell during

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

try this instead.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: The cell attribute that I would like to alter is the width of the cell. This is not possible in tableview: heightForRowAtIndexPath. The appearance that I desire is displayed just fine once I scroll to the cells that are not shown as soon as the tableview appears (without me scrolling). I am looking to get the same effect with the cells that appear first.

Comment: Changing the width of a cell is a very bad idea. If you insist on going it you should rather make the cell have a clearColor background and have a subview on the cell that you resize when you want to do your resize. You could do this subview resizing in cellforindexpath delegate method. If you do it elsewhere you're going to have issues during reuse of cells.

Comment: if you know what you are doing, I would recommend using
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;